# What is the best way to equate NULL columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null, equality

I am performing a `MERGE` between two tables

```
MERGE indexdecomp.Constituent targ
USING (SELECT ic.ConstituentName           
       FROM   indexdecomp.IndexConstituents ic) src
ON (((targ.Name = src.ConstituentName) OR (targ.Name IS NULL AND src.ConstituentName IS NULL)))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
UPDATE SET
    targ.Name = src.ConstituentName
;
```

and in my `ON` clause I have the following predicate:

```
(targ.Name = src.ConstituentName) OR (targ.Name IS NULL AND src.ConstituentName IS NULL)
```

I have this predicate since I am considering it a match if both Names are equal or if both names are `null.

Is there a better or more conventional way to handle equality between two `null` columns? What way would produce the quickest execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this: ([SQL ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx))

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;

MERGE indexdecomp.Constituent targ
USING (SELECT ic.ConstituentName           
   FROM #IndexConstituents ic) src
ON (((targ.Name = src.ConstituentName)))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
UPDATE SET
    targ.Name = src.ConstituentName;

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
```

But that seems to be a pretty heavy trade off for lumping off a predicate and neither is very readable. You could actually abstract this mess with a UDF that takes two string arguments and returns a boolean.

Something like:

```
create function StrNullCompare(@a varchar(max), @b varchar(max))
returns int
as
begin
    if ((@a = @b) or (@a is null and @b is null)) return 1;

    return 0;
end

-- tests
select dbo.StrNullCompare('wer', 'were');
select dbo.StrNullCompare('wer', 'wer');
select dbo.StrNullCompare('hi', null);
select dbo.StrNullCompare(null, null);
```

And your predicate becomes:

```
(dbo.StrNullCompare(targ.Name, src.ConstituentName)=1)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this or is it possible to do it by rewriting the predicate? According to the MSDN it seems that setting ANSI_NULLS OFF isn't future proof.

Comment: Yes. Create a UDF... per my most recent edit. That way you get a future-proof and reusable function which would also be more readable than eith the ANSI NULL or extra predicate solution.

Comment: Added a sample UDF as a concrete example of what I was talking about

Answer (score 2):

You could try..

```
ISNULL (targ. Name,'a magic string value') =ISNULL (src.ConstituentName,'a magic string value')
```

Of course add your own magic string as appropriate for example use newid () to get a guid and use that.

Not really sure if this is "better" than an and or but is a little more human readable; worth benchmarking and testing both approaches though.